# Problema con instalación y uso de módulo quandl

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy intentando trabajar con el módulo quandl para descargar datos económicos con python.
Aparentemente todo es correcto y en la lista de módulos instalados aparece la versión correcta, pero no me deja trabajar con él. me sale el siguiente error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xxxxxx", line 1, in <module>
    import quandl
  File "xxxxxx", line 3, in <module>
    quandl.ApiConfig.api_key = "myApiKey"
NameError: name 'Quandl' is not defined
```

Es curioso porque mi programa solo tiene dos líneas, y en el mensaje de error pone que hay un error en la "línea 3", con una instrucción que no está en mi programa. Mi código es este:

```
import quandl
print(quandl.api_key)
```

También me llama la atención que en el `NameError` pone 'Quandl', con mayúscula, y que en la lista de instalación (ver imagen) el nombre del módulo aparece en mayúscula. He probado a escribir Quandl en mayúscula y en minúscula, con diferentes combinaciones, pero no obtengo resultado.

También he probado desinstalando y reinstalando con diferentes comandos, pero no consigo conectar.

¿Alguna idea?

[image: lista de módulos instalados]

Answer (score 0):

Después de muchos intentos y pruebas, el problema se solucionó usando un comando ligeramente diferente en la instalación del paquete. Mi versión de python es la 3.9x, así que en vez de usar `pip install quandl`, he usado `pip3 install quandl`.
Ahora funciona todo correctamente.